# Casting ((DWORD) 0xFFFFFFFF) to single precision float without changing binary value

Tags: c, casting, rom

I want to compile a single precision float into flash as `0xFFFFFFFF` (unitialized flash).

When I try `(FLOAT32) ((UINT32) 0xFFFFFFFF)`, it converts to a floating point `(0x0000804F)` during the compilation process instead of `0xFFFFFFFF`.

This applies to the initialization of a field in a struct in file scope. When I think of it, this means that the compiler is expecting a FLOAT32 literal.

I am beginning to wonder whether this is actually possible.

[EDIT: This applies to initialization of a field in a struct in file scope]

Answer (score 5):

In C, the best way is to use a `union`.  Store into the `UINT32` field, then read it out from the `float` field.

Complete discussion here: [How to convert or cast a float into its bit sequence such as a long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796355/how-to-convert-or-cast-a-float-into-its-bit-sequence-such-as-a-long)

Also, if you have C99 features available, you can use designated initializers to specify which of the union fields you want to assign.  Even if you don't have C99 you can just make sure that the `UINT32` fields in the `union` is the first one, so it will be assigned by default.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: Thanks. Great suggestion and link. Unfortunately, this only works in block scope and not file scope (which I need to use).

Comment: @ChristianMadsen that changes things. I added an answer for that.

Comment: ChristianMadsen why do you think this doesn't work in file scope?  @eznme gave a code example showing exactly how to use this for static initialization at file scope.

Comment: And @bkausbk gave two examples, one showing the C99 designated initializer feature and one showing plain C.

Answer (score 2):

As you request in the comment: here at non-block-scope (you can make global- or file-scope):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef union {
    uint32_t uint32;
    float f;
} aliasing;
aliasing a = { 0xffffffff };
int main(){
    printf("%u %f\n", a.uint32, a.f); // output: 4294967295 -1.#QNAN0
    return 0;
}
```

Also, if you want it inside a struct (your original question) and still want static initialization you can do:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef union {
    uint32_t uint32;
    float f;
} aliasing;
typedef struct {
    aliasing a;
    int otherstuff;
} thestruct_t;
thestruct_t thestruct = { { 0xffffffff }, 0 };
int main(){
    printf("%u %f\n", thestruct.a.uint32, thestruct.a.f); 
         // output: 4294967295 -1.#QNAN0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `printf("%" PRIu32 " %f\n", a.uint32, a.f)` for sizeof(unsigned) may be 2.

Comment: I for got to mention that I cannot change the definition of the struct type. I am only allowed to change the value of the field. Like: typedef struct {
    float myfloat;
} thestruct_t;thestruct_t thestruct = { { 0xffffffff }, 0 };

Answer (score 1):

I think using unions and then casting any type to it would work:

```
typedef union _DATA {
    UINT32 AsInteger;
    FLOAT AsFloat;
} DATA;

char* Buffer = malloc(...);
ReadFromFile(Buffer, 1000);

// Casting
// ((DATA*) (Buffer + Offset))->AsFloat
// ((DATA*) (Buffer + Offset))->AsInteger
```

Or statically

```
DATA MyData;
MyData.AsInteger = 0xffffffff;

// C99
DATA MyData = {.AsInteger = 0xffffffff};

// C
DATA MyData = {0xffffffff};
```

Comment: Don't use identifiers starting with an underscore like `_DATA`; it's too easy to invade the implementation name space and cause undefined behavior. Especially when followed by a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to use absolute placement. It may or may not be possible with your tools.

Note: I have never done this and syntax here isn't probably even valid on any compiler. This is only an example of the intention.

```
UINT32 const i = 0xFFFFFFFF @ 0x12345678; /* Place i at address 0x12345678 */
extern FLASH32 const f @ 0x12345678;  /* Pretend that f is at the same address */
```