# Casting a float for int and int to float

Tags: c, pointers, casting, floating-point

Having a little difficulty with pointers. I have to store a float in an array of unsigned ints and be able to pull it out.

I know there is a special way to cast this so I don't reorder the bits, I think this is the correct way to store it when I want to put it into the array:

```
float f = 5.0;
int newF = (int *) f;
arrayOfInts[0] = *newF
```

Which seems to successfully store the value in the array.
However, at some point I have to pull the value back out of the array of ints, this is where my confusion comes in (assuming I inputed into the array correctly)

```
float * f = (float *) arrayOfInts[0]
int result = *f;
```

however, that gives me the warning: 'cast to pointer from integer of different size'

I can't really think of how to solve that without some sort of long cast.. which doesn't seem right..

I don't want to lose the value or damage the bits.. obviously It will lose decimal point precision.. but I know theirs some way to safety convert back and forth

Comment: Not always `int` and `float` have same alignment. And you are casting an `int` to `float *`.  And if you intend to store value in `int` variable then why use a cast ? And if `result` is `float` then cast the value as `float` why use pointer in between ?

Comment: @ameyCU I found somewhere else on the web "You need to use a pointer cast. If you cast float to int that will change the bits. You want to cast (float *) to (int *) so that the bits are not disturbed."

Comment: so I am not completely sure what I was doing but I was being careful

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796355/how-to-convert-or-cast-a-float-into-its-bit-sequence-such-as-a-long.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to store a float in an array of unsigned ints and be able to pull it out.

Use a `union` and `unsigned char[]`.  `unsigned char` is specified to not have any padding and all bit combinations are valid.  This is not always true of many other number types.  By overlaying the `float` with `unsigned char[]`, code can examine each "byte" of the `float`, one at a time.

```
union {
  float f;
  unsigned char uc[sizeof (float)];
} x;

// example usage
x.f = 1.234f;
for (unsigned i = 0; i<sizeof x.uc; i++) {
  printf("%u:%u\n", i, 1u*x.uc[i]);
}
```

Sample output: Yours may vary

```
0:182
1:243
2:157
3:63
```

`float` --> `unsigned char[]` --> `float` is always safe.

`unsigned char[]` --> `float` --> `unsigned char[]` is not always safe as a combination of `unsigned char[]` *may* not have a valid `float` value.

Avoid pointer tricks and casting.  There are alignment and size issues.

```
// Poor code
float f = 5.0f;
int newF = *((int *) &f);  // Conversion of `float*` to `int*` is not well specified.
```

---

Code can also overlay with fixed-width no-padding types like `(u)int32_t` if they exist (they usually do) and match in size.

```
#include <stdint.h>
union {
  float f;
  uint32_t u32;
} x32;


#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// example usage
assert(sizeof x32.f == sizeof x32.u32);
x32.f = 1.234f;
printf("%" PRNu32 "\n", x32.u32);
}
```

Example output: yours may vary

```
1067316150
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a float to an int

```
float fval = 123.4f;
int ival = *(int*)&fval;
```

To convert back

```
int ival = /* from float */
float fval = *(float*) &ival;
```

it won't work if float and int are different sizes, but presumably you know that already. The unsigned char union method outlined in other answer for chux is more robust, but over-complicated for what you probably want to do.

Comment: DONT do this: this violates strict aliasing rules; even if it compiles you may end up with junk values.